# Getting 'Unable to cast object of type' error when trying to loop through Button controls on Form

Tags: c#, winforms, button, casting, tablelayoutpanel

In a `Form`, I added a `TableLayoutPanel`, and within that I add 5 buttons.

At runtime, I add 10 buttons to Form1 in a loop. Then I use `foreach` to do something with those 10 buttons.

```
foreach (Button C in this.Controls)
    // do something
```

When I the run the program, an error appears:

> Unable to cast object of type 'System.Windows.Forms.TableLayoutPanel' to type 'System.Windows.Forms.Button'

I think this error happens because the `TableLayoutPanel` contains 5 buttons in it.

Yeah I can delete this `TableLayoutPanel` and add 5 buttons directly in the `Form`, but the `TableLayoutPanel` helps a lot in my code.

So is there any solution to traverse those 10 buttons and still keep the `TableLayoutPanel`?

Furthermore, can I traverse "buttons in Form" and "buttons in TableLayoutPanel" separately ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your current code is going to try to iterate over ALL controls on the Form *(well, all top-level controls anyway.. you'd need to use recursion to iterate through all controls nested within other controls),* then cast each to a `Button`, hence the exception you're getting.

Just specify which controls you want to iterate over:

```
foreach (var button in this.Controls.OfType<Button>())
{
    // now you'll iterate over just the Button controls
}
```

If you want to just iterate over the controls in the `TableLayoutPanel` *(I don't think that's the case; I think you've got Buttons directly on the Form and more Buttons in the TableLayoutPanel, and you want to loop over the Buttons on the Form itself),* then reference that child control instead:

```
foreach (var button in tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.OfType<Button>())
{
    // iterate over the Button controls inside the TableLayoutPanel
}
```

Answer (score 3):

> System.Windows.Forms.TableLayoutPanel' to type 'System.Windows.Forms.Button'

As the error explains you try to caste elements for a type that it cannot be caste.

Reason :  foreach loop

```
foreach (Button C in this.Controls) // Button is the wrong type caste
```

`this.Controls` will return every control in your current form, this include other form elements like `TableLayoutPanel` which cannot be cast to a `button`. So filter them as follow.

Answer :

```
foreach (var C in this.Controls){
     if(c.GetType()== typeof(Button)){
          Button btn = (Button)item; //do work using this
      } 
}
```

Note : If buttons are reside inside another controller this approach will not provide them. Instead you need to access the specific control and loop in it.

Answer (score 2):

Form.Controls is of type [ControlCollection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.controlcollection%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), so your code might not run!
Use below code instead:

```
foreach (Control C in this.Controls)
{
    // do something
}
```

or

```
foreach(Button b in this.Controls.OfType<Button>())
{
   //do something
}
```